# Javascript XML Parser Error with attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

i want to split this xml structure to get the "Data" value.

```html
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = '<Row><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Description</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Priority</Data></Cell></Row>';

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Data")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

The Problem is this XML is the "ss:Type" Attribute, it only gets the Data when you remove the "ss:Type" like this

```
<Cell><Data>ID</Data></Cell>
```

So my question is how to write the code, to get the "Data" value?

Comment: Can you modify the XML a bit i.e adding namespace declaration for prefix `ss`? Namespace prefix need to be declared within the XML, otherwise the document doesn't conform to XML spec and therefore can't be parsed using XML parser.

Comment: I have to see if its possible thanks